# rsyslogd[xxxx]: error during config processing: STOP is followed by unreachable statements

Tags: centos, syslog, rsyslog

I have the following configuration in master syslog server:

```
[root@STGSYSLOG ~]# egrep -v "^$|^#" /etc/rsyslog.conf
$MaxMessageSize 32k
$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
$ModLoad imjournal # provides access to the systemd journal
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514
$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 514
$template RemoteLogs,"/var/log/RemoteLogs/%fromhost-ip%/%PROGRAMNAME%.log"
*.* ?RemoteLogs
& stop
$WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf
$OmitLocalLogging on
$IMJournalStateFile imjournal.state
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log
[root@STGSYSLOG ~]#
```

Version of rsyslog is:

```
[root@STGSYSLOG ~]# rsyslogd -v
rsyslogd 8.24.0-52.el7_8.2
```

I am getting the following error while checking the configuration:

```
[root@STGSYSLOG ~]# rsyslogd -f /etc/rsyslog.conf -N1
rsyslogd: version 8.24.0-52.el7_8.2, config validation run (level 1), master config /etc/rsyslog.conf
rsyslogd: error during config processing: STOP is followed by unreachable statements!  [v8.24.0-52.el7_8.2 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]
[root@STGSYSLOG ~]#
```

There is a line “& stop”, which instructs rsyslog to stop processing the messages once it is written to a file. If you don’t include “& stop”, messages will instead be written to the local files.
Am I doing anything wrong here? or the parameter is deprecated in the rsyslog 8.x version? Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

This page appears in search results referencing a stop directive error relating to rsyslog.
Posting a response in hopes of making resolution easier for those that follow.

---

Ranjith,

Based on your config file, it appears you're attempting to achieve the same result I've been working to solve:

- Receiving remote syslog messages which are logged to appropriately named local log files based on the defined template, and
- Continuing to log local messages to standard local log files as directed in the remaining portion of the config file.

Based on the above, my response is as follows.

Yes, the stop directive is unconditional and causes the remainder of the configuration file to be ignored (generating the error message you've referenced).
I've discovered that using "rulesets" achieves the goal without the error.

I'm using Debian 10.8 and [rsyslog] v8.1901.0-1.

The relevant portions of my [rsyslog.conf]:

In the Modules section:

```
# provides UDP syslog reception
module(load="imudp")
input(type="imudp" port="514" ruleset="remote")  # "remote" ruleset defined below...

# provides TCP syslog reception
module(load="imtcp")
input(type="imtcp" port="514" ruleset="remote") # "remote" ruleset defined below...
```

I'm aware that documentation states the ruleset must be defined *before* being bound... That doesn't appear to be true in my case as of this writing.

In the Rules section:

```
$template Incoming-logs,"var/log/%HOSTNAME%/%PROGRAMNAME%.log
ruleset(name="remote"){
action(type="omfile" dynafile="Incoming-logs")
}               # This ruleset is used above where it is bound 
                #  to the TCP/UDP listener definitions
```

This finally achieved my goal... And with no error/warning messages.

Hope this helps.